# How to make tomcat 8 load jars with the same classloader as wars?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have class (com.example.Example) that located in {catalina.home}/lib/app and when I try to cast it in webapp to com.example.Example I get classCastException. I have found similar question on the stackoverflow and answer was that it because it used different classloaders.  Can I use the same classloader for {catalina.home}/lib/* and for webapps-* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just exclude jars from the war/WEB-INF/lib and it began work well